# How I can get the User Name, System name and OS of the machine within particular domain?

Tags: windows

I was given a task to collect list of users have not updated to windows 10 . Can any one help me in finding the easiest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Getting System Name and OS is a trivial task of [Inventorying Computers with AD PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2010/02/04/inventorying-computers-with-ad-powershell/):

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem -Wrap –Auto
```

However, the user name is not a property of a computer, as by default all the domain users can use all the domain computers. Therefore, you can't list it with [`Get-ADComputer` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx). This is something you should catalog when assigning computers to users. (Also, users shouldn't upgrade operating systems: it's a task for the IT department – I hope that's just me reading the question too literally.)

If your users seldom use other computers than their own, you could gather information on last logged in users to determine computer/user pairs. For this there's plenty of different solutions, but here's two possible alternatives:
 [`Get-LastLogon` script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LastLogon-Determining-283f98ae) and this ["crazy-oneliner"](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2013/03/powershell-find-the-name-and-time-of-the-last-logged-on-user/) from The Scripting Dutchman.